# My display name is cut off

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, display-names

A few days ago, I changed my display name from "ValekHalfHeart" to "Approaching Darkness Fish". Now, my longer username is not fully displayed. Example:

[image: Approaching Darkness "Fi"]

Alternatively, just look to the lower right:

[image: Recursive Approaching Darkness "Fi"]

I find this ugly and frustrating. Is there an effective upper limit on display names on SO, or this just the result of my recent name change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are limited to 30 characters for your display name, **however** there is no set number of characters that will always display in those boxes. You get 145px of space - the width of the container which contains your display name on a post. Anything that goes past that will simply be cut off. Yours happens to cut off very nicely at the end of a letter - not everyone's long display name does that.

It should be noted that your *entire* display name *is* there - you can just only see 145px of it. The display name length has to be limited so other things can fit onto the page, like the editor to the left, and the post options to the left of *that*.

Comment: Thx... frustrating though that after learning this I need to wait 30 days before I can remove 2 spaces to make it fit.

Comment: @App There is a workaround: create a profile on another SE site and change the name there, propagating the change across all your profiles.