# maximum size for display names?

Tags: discussion, display-names

I've came across a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99%EF%BC%99) with huge display name:

[image]

Is there any size limit for display names?

Comment: Max 30 characters. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278111/my-display-name-is-cut-off/278112#278112).

Answer (score 3):

Your display name is limited to 30 characters and 145 pixels.

[Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278112/1768232)

> You are limited to 30 characters for your display name, **however** there is no set number of characters that will always display in those boxes. You get 145px of space - the width of the container which contains your display name on a post. Anything that goes past that will simply be cut off. Yours happens to cut off very nicely at the end of a letter - not everyone's long display name does that.
>
> It should be noted that your *entire* display name *is* there - you can just only see 145px of it. The display name length has to be limited so other things can fit onto the page, like the editor to the left, and the post options to the left of *that*.

Comment: Thank you, should it be "30 characters **OR** 145 pixels"?

Comment: @PedroLobito no, I think it should just be *"30 characters"*. 145px applies in the user card but, as you've seen, display size limits elsewhere are different.